# form_set_error highlights only select fields and not other required field types

Tags: 7, theming

I have a content type with few required fields. When I try to save a node without filling any data, all the required fields throw an error message saying the field is required, but the required fields aren't highlighted in red. Only the select fields are highlighted; date fields or text fields aren't.

> [image]

This is happening when I use the [Zero Point](https://www.drupal.org/project/zeropoint) theme (version 7.x-4.10).

How should I proceed with troubleshooting?

Comment: Hi @kiamlaluno, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi, any suggestions/ tips on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of CSS overwritten by Zero Point theme, added more classes in my custom CSS file:

```
    /* .form-item input.error, */
    .form-wrapper .fieldset-wrapper .form-item input.error,
    .form-item textarea.error,
    .form-item select.error {
            border: 2px solid red;
    }
```